# Space curve. Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to apply Stokes over the toroidal spiral with equation, for example, $$x = (4 + \sin(20 t))\cos(t),\  y = (4 + \sin(20t))\sin(t),\  z = \cos(20t).$$ I'd like to know if somebody has any idea about what surface this curve is boundary, if this surface exists, of course. What about the slinky curve( with equation, for example,

$$x = \sin(40t),\  y = (2 + \cos(40t))\cos(t),\ z = (2 + \cos(40t))\sin(t) ) ?$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If you distribute the different pieces, you start to see some circular like pieces generated. But since the function has a period, eventually they look back around to each other. You clearly already know what this is (even if you don't realize it!) A rather abstract hint is: you probably know $\langle \cos t, \sin t\rangle, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ parametrizes a circle. But does $\langle \sin t, \cos t \rangle, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$ parametrize a circle? What is the relation between the parameterizations. How does this relate to your example?

After a bit of staring I believe you will see it. It will probably be a 'face palm' moment when you do. In any case, after struggling with for a bit if you still need help, [look at this and see.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7B(4%2BSin%5B20t%5D)Cos%5Bt%5D,(4%2BSin%5B20t%5D)Sin%5Bt%5D,Cos%5B20t%5D%7D,%7Bt,0,2Pi%7D%5D)

Comment: I didn't understand your hint very well. If it's not asking too much, could you draw(plot) the surface, please? I can't see the solution in any way.

Comment: @danilocn94 I linked a plot of the curve

Comment: But I want the surface on which this curve is boundary( to apply Stokes' theorem).

Comment: @danilocn94 Again, you should be able to get this from the picture of the curve.

Comment: So, What would the equation of this surface be ?

Comment: I understood that drawing lines from this curve to the origin, the union of all these lines is the surface. What I want now is the equation of this surface. Do you know what it would  be ?

Comment: It is a torus. I leave it to you to look at the standard parametrization for the torus and use your curve to write down the equation of the torus.

Comment: It can't be a torus because it is a closed surface so it has no boundary.

Comment: I think you are confused about your question versus what I am answering. The curve lies on (really in) a torus. It simply fixes a variable in the parametrization for the torus. This is what you asked in the sense of this is a surface that the curves sits on. Is it the boundary of something? Who knows?! It would be the boundary of many things.

Comment: I think what you want to ask is if you can apply Stokes' Theorem to this. The surface is closed. But no boundary? What do you mean by boundary?! For example, boundary in the sense of the Divergence Theorem is really a volume. In the sense of Stokes' Theorem (depending on the dimension) it cannot mean a volume. You are right in that the torus has no boundary in the sense you mean it. So I leave it to you to figure out what that means in the way of applying Stokes' Theorem to this problem. Enough has been said at this point here so I will not reply on this thread any more.